# SVG color does not work with all SVG graphics

Tags: html, css, svg

**Goal:** I want to style an SVG graphic using style classes (stroke color). I have read that this is done with color.

**Problem:** The style is applied to one graphic and not to another svg.

**Question:** I would like to know why this is?

```css
.voted svg path {
    color: green;
}

svg {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="voted">
  <svg class="" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 25h32L18 9 2 25Z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
</button>

<button class="voted">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 106.16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 106.16" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M4.02,44.6h27.36c2.21,0,4.02,1.81,4.02,4.03v53.51c0,2.21-1.81,4.03-4.02,4.03H4.02 c-2.21,0-4.02-1.81-4.02-4.03V48.63C0,46.41,1.81,44.6,4.02,44.6L4.02,44.6z M63.06,4.46c2.12-10.75,19.72-0.85,20.88,16.48 c0.35,5.3-0.2,11.47-1.5,18.36l25.15,0c10.46,0.41,19.59,7.9,13.14,20.2c1.47,5.36,1.69,11.65-2.3,14.13 c0.5,8.46-1.84,13.7-6.22,17.84c-0.29,4.23-1.19,7.99-3.23,10.88c-3.38,4.77-6.12,3.63-11.44,3.63H55.07 c-6.73,0-10.4-1.85-14.8-7.37V51.31c12.66-3.42,19.39-20.74,22.79-32.11V4.46L63.06,4.46z"/></g></svg>
</button>
```

Comment: You didn't set the fill. Add `fill="currentColor"` to the second path

Comment: @enxaneta yes you are right. and it works. It was my mistake. I will change my question. Why color only apply to the first svg and not to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SVG uses fill/stroke rather than color.
- The only reason color works in the first case is that it has fill="currentColor" that sets the fill to whatever the color is.

```css
.voted svg path {
    fill: green;
}

svg {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="voted">
  <svg class="" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 25h32L18 9 2 25Z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
</button>

<button class="voted">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 106.16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 106.16" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M4.02,44.6h27.36c2.21,0,4.02,1.81,4.02,4.03v53.51c0,2.21-1.81,4.03-4.02,4.03H4.02 c-2.21,0-4.02-1.81-4.02-4.03V48.63C0,46.41,1.81,44.6,4.02,44.6L4.02,44.6z M63.06,4.46c2.12-10.75,19.72-0.85,20.88,16.48 c0.35,5.3-0.2,11.47-1.5,18.36l25.15,0c10.46,0.41,19.59,7.9,13.14,20.2c1.47,5.36,1.69,11.65-2.3,14.13 c0.5,8.46-1.84,13.7-6.22,17.84c-0.29,4.23-1.19,7.99-3.23,10.88c-3.38,4.77-6.12,3.63-11.44,3.63H55.07 c-6.73,0-10.4-1.85-14.8-7.37V51.31c12.66-3.42,19.39-20.74,22.79-32.11V4.46L63.06,4.46z"/></g></svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert! I was update my question. Why color only works for the first svg and not to the second. Did you know that?

Comment: Good Morning Robert! Your answer is great, clear and it works. Top!!.  I would like to know why color works for the first and not for the second. Only for understanding.

Comment: The answer already tells you why. So again, what is unclear about the answer?

Comment: I had read over it at first. Thank you! now i understand :-)